# babel.transform _babelCore2.default.transform Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

In `node.js` **(v6.8.0)**, I try to use *babel* to transform a *string* containing `js` code and then use *eval* to execute it.

**main.js**:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');
...
const s2 = babel.transform(s1, { presets: ['latest', 'stage-0'] }).code;
const r = eval(s2);
...
```

If I just run it with node without transforming `main.js` using *babel*, it works fine.

But if I also transform `main.js` using *babel* (with `npm script 'babel src -d dist'`), then `'babel.transform'` becomes `'_babelCore2.default.transform'`, then I get the *error*:

```
Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined
```

How do I fix it or is there a way to tell *babel* not to *transform* `'babel.transform'`?

Comment: post your full code please,how you are importing the transform function from the babel core.

Comment: He isn't. transform is something that babel is transpiling. It is not transpiling correctly. I assume its a configuration problem, not something to do with his particular code.